# GitHub Education сделает ли публичным моё учебное заведение

Tags: github

Хочу получить GitHub Copilot, но для этого нужно указать свою школу/колледж/универ в GitHub Global Campus. Если я укажу и пройду процесс подтверждения, будет ли всем видно где я учусь?